# `names` pointing to `by` instead

Tags: r, methods, namespaces

The following happened within one R session:

```
c("cyl", "mpg") %in% names(mtcars)
```

> Error in by.data.frame(mtcars) :
>
> argument "INDICES" is missing, with no default

Indeed, calling `names` showed `by`!

```
names
#function (data, INDICES, FUN, ..., simplify = TRUE) 
#UseMethod("by")
#<bytecode: 0x475e718>
#<environment: namespace:base>
```

Calling `base::names` was fine: `function (x)  .Primitive("names")`

I restarted R session by clicking RStudio's menu option, but it didn't help. Closing RStudio did (i.e. `names` correctly displaying `function (x)  .Primitive("names")`) and I am no longer able to reproduce this.

How could this happen?

My session at that moment (Freya is a fork of Ubuntu 14.04):

```
sessionInfo()
# R version 3.3.2 (2016-10-31)
# Platform: x86_64-pc-linux-gnu (64-bit)
# Running under: elementary OS Freya
# 
# locale:
# [1] LC_CTYPE=en_US.UTF-8       LC_NUMERIC=C              
# [3] LC_TIME=cs_CZ.UTF-8        LC_COLLATE=en_US.UTF-8    
# [5] LC_MONETARY=cs_CZ.UTF-8    LC_MESSAGES=en_US.UTF-8   
# [7] LC_PAPER=cs_CZ.UTF-8       LC_NAME=C                 
# [9] LC_ADDRESS=C               LC_TELEPHONE=C            
# [11] LC_MEASUREMENT=cs_CZ.UTF-8 LC_IDENTIFICATION=C       
# 
# attached base packages:
# [1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base     
# 
# other attached packages:
# [1] moodler_0.1 tidyr_0.6.0 dplyr_0.5.0
# 
# loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
# [1] lazyeval_0.2.0 magrittr_1.5   R6_2.2.0       assertthat_0.1 DBI_0.5-1     
# [6] tools_3.3.2    tibble_1.2     Rcpp_0.12.8    stringi_1.1.2  RMySQL_0.10.9 
# [11] openxlsx_3.0.0
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The most obvious way this would happen, and continue to be the case across a restart of the session in RStudio, is simply a `names <- by` assignment at some point in your code.

However since you are unable to reproduce, it is impossible to know whether the answer is this simple, or the assignment was the consequence of a more complicated operation.

Comment: Interestingly, doing this also messed up my File Browser in RStudio :p

Comment: You are probably right ...and because RStudio preserves global environment when restarting a session, it would leave the reassigned `names` in place. There is no obvious point in my code that would reassign `names` to `by`, but I did name one of my arguments "by", so dark magic could have happened when parsing the input.

Comment: Rstudio keeps the history cross session pretty well so you can look in there to see if you can find a situation where you call `names <- by` or `names = by`